# Jquery hide and show with html5 data attributes

Tags: html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to use jquery show and hide methods with html5 attributes.

Here is what i'm trying to do:

html file :

```
<div class="test" data-location="paris">Math</div>
<div class="test" data-location="paris">Physics</div>
<div class="test" data-location="paris">Chemistry</div>
<div class="test" data-location="paris">Biology</div>
```

script:

```
$("[data-location="paris"]").hide();
```

I'm using the jquery to hide all the divs with data-location="paris". I don't know why i can't do it. Help?

Comment: try to remove additional quotes `$("[data-location=paris]").hide();`

Comment: If you're going to add quotes before and after paris, make sure to escape them.`$("[data-location=\"paris\"]").hide();`

Comment: @vladkras that doesn't work too.

Comment: @AnudeepKatragadda nope, it works: [proof](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/3rcd1wnc/). Maybe you have some errors before, check your console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this.

```
$("[data-location='paris']").hide();
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/getmanzooronline/3rcd1wnc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use single quotes instead of double.  This will work: `$("[data-location='paris']").hide();`

Or escape your double quotes, like this:

`$("[data-location=\"paris\"]").hide();`

You were ending your code statement early.  $(**"**[data-location=**"** was all that was being run.  Big error there!